# Java game not working

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I found this java source code for a brick breaker game online. I downloaded it and tried to run it but it gives me a NullPointerException. What is giving this exception and how do I fix it? Thanks.

http://zetcode.com/tutorials/javagamestutorial/breakout/

Here is the stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(ImageIcon.java:181)
    at Ball.<init>(Ball.java:16)
    at Board.gameInit(Board.java:48)
    at Board.addNotify(Board.java:43)
    at java.awt.Container.addNotify(Container.java:2578)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(JComponent.java:4685)
    at java.awt.Container.addNotify(Container.java:2578)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(JComponent.java:4685)
    at java.awt.Container.addNotify(Container.java:2578)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(JComponent.java:4685)
    at javax.swing.JRootPane.addNotify(JRootPane.java:739)
    at java.awt.Container.addNotify(Container.java:2578)
    at java.awt.Window.addNotify(Window.java:663)
    at java.awt.Frame.addNotify(Frame.java:470)
    at java.awt.Window.show(Window.java:859)
    at java.awt.Component.show(Component.java:1584)
    at java.awt.Component.setVisible(Component.java:1536)
    at java.awt.Window.setVisible(Window.java:842)
    at Breakout.<init>(Breakout.java:14)
    at Breakout.main(Breakout.java:18)
Exception in thread "Timer-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Board$ScheduleTask.run(Board.java:110)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:512)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:462)
```

Apparently this code is supposed to work, but it isn't.

Comment: Which java version are you using to compile the game??, donwload the last version

Comment: @DGomez  The exception output does not indicate a version mismatch.  See the answer.

Answer (score 5):

You probably didn't download the images as well, or at least didn't put them in the right folder. Make sure you put the images here:

Browse to Ball.java, go two folder levels up, create there a folder called images and put there your images.

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying. I have the image files in the right place.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you don't. Otherwise Class.getResource() wouldn't return null.

Comment: I had two "." instead of one for my file locations. That's what messed it up. I had my images in the same folder as my class files. I got it working now. Thank you.